# URL rewrite with pagination using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

Original URL is `www.example.com/photos?album=album-name&page=page-number`

Need a clean URL like...

Displaying all album URLs should be like

- `www.example.com/photos`

When opening an album or on page 1 or return to page 1, URL should be like

- `www.example.com/photos/album-name`

and when the user is on 2nd page URL should be like

- `www.example.com/photos/album-name/page-number`

Comment: Have you already changed the URLs in your application - so you are already linking to the correct "canonical" URLs?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([\w-]+)$ $1.php?album=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/([\w-]+)/([\d-]+)$ $1.php?album=$2&page=$3 [L]
```

Comment: Rather than duplicating conditions several times (ie. _not a file and not a directory then..._), it is usually preferable to include a single negated exception at the start instead. ie. _is a file or a directory then do nothing_.